# In Solovay-Kitaev's algorithm, where does the rotation relation $\sin(\theta / 2) = 2 \sin^2(\phi/2)\sqrt{1 - \sin^4(\phi/2)}$ come from?

Tags: solovay-kitaev-algorithm

In Dawson's and Nielsen's pedagogical review of the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm, they describe the decomposition of U into $U=VWV^\dagger W^\dagger$, with both $V, W$ being unitary, being rotated by $\phi$ around the x-axis and y-axis, and obeying the following relationship, where $\theta$ is the angle of $U$ about the Bloch sphere:

$$ \sin(\theta / 2) = 2 \sin^2(\phi/2)\sqrt{1 - \sin^4(\phi/2)}$$

Where does this relation come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply comes from equation an arbitrary rotation $R_{n}(\theta)$ with the rotation
$$
U=R_X(\phi)R_Y(\phi)R_X(-\phi)R_Y(-\phi).
$$

The way that I did this calculation, just to verify this claim, was to recognise that, for example
$$
R_X(\phi)=\cos\frac{\phi}{2}I+i\sin\frac{\phi}{2}X.
$$
Now, if I evaluate $\text{Tr}(U)$, this picks out the identity terms in the product (because I certainly don't want to multiply the whole thing out!), and those terms occur whenever I have a pair of $X$ or a pair of $Y$ (or both or neither). Hence
\begin{align}
\cos\frac{\theta}{2}&=\cos^4\frac{\phi}{2}+2\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2}\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}-\sin^4\frac{\phi}{2} \\
&=(\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2}+\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2})^2-2\sin^4\frac{\phi}{2} \\
&=1-2\sin^4\frac{\phi}{2}.
\end{align}
Now if you use this to express $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$, you'll find the claimed result.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, this explains it.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, for the last step, one has to factor out $(\cos^2\theta/2 + \sin^2\theta/2)$